# postman или python

Tags: парсер, curl, postman, crawling

Делаю запрос через postman:

```
get: `https://www.mobile.de/ru/категория/автомобили/vhc:car`
```

Без хэдеров, без аргументов.

И делаю запрос курлом:

```
curl -X GET   https://www.mobile.de/ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C/vhc:car   -H 'Postman-Token: d23d606f-9ee1-498b-b7b9-37b306f4ddb1'   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Ответы получаю различные. Как сервер определяет, что ходит к нему постман и что к нему ходит curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пульните в https://httpbin.org и посмотрите действительно ли нет дополнительных заголовков?

По умолчанию постман и курл шлют User-Agent.

Comment: Да, всё так. Я увидел это. Но Вы раньше меня ответили. За это вам и ставлю checked. Мне всегда казалось, что ни curl, ни postman этого не делают